# Android: Timer onTick problem

Tags: android, algorithm

Hi I'm working on one of my project then I encountered this problem, well I don't know if it is a bug or something I just want to share hoping to get some answer to enlighten my day. So here's the problem:

I made a countdown timer for my project which will run for 2 minutes (that will be 120 seconds) 1000 is the interval time (1000ms = 1s) then I set a checker, an integer of 120 (declared globally) which will be diminished by one each time the timer ticks. The integer will be shown on a textView counting down. then will show a message when the integer reaches the onFinish of the timer. That message will give how much time I've spent by deducting the declared integer by 120.

The problem here is that the timer stops before it reaches 1 given that it will not be deducted by the last tick. The hardest part is that sometimes it stops with 4 or even 5 on the remaining time. Can Anyone help me about this one? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code for further understanding:

```
//declared a timer
int timer = 120;

//starts the timer
gameTimer = new gameTimer(120000, 1000);
    gameTimer.start();

private class gameTimer extends CountDownTimer{
public gameTimer(long startTime, long interval)
{
    super(startTime, interval);
}

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
   //on tick deduct timer by 1
  timer -= 1;   
   TextView timer1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
   timer1.setText(""+timer);
}

public void onFinish()
{
    //PERFORM END ACTION UPON FINISHING THE GAME
    endtime = 120 - timer;
    TextView endtime1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    1.setText(""+endtime);
}
}
```

Comment: try to pass the context to your CountDownTimer, and when you want to display the timer on the TextView , you should use Activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable);

Comment: Just making it clear, when the `onFinish()` callback fires, the `endtime` value is above 1? (or 2, 3, 4 etc)

Comment: the value of the endtime should have : 120, because the value of timer is decremented by 1 each seconde :). so i think that is a problem of who call the UI , the countDownTimer is a thread, but he is not an UI THread  , that's why i said that he should pass the context to his class and override the method runOnUIThread() . what do you think MeLight??

Comment: @MeLight nope, the thing is the timer1 value stops at the value of 2,3,4 or 5 randomly when the onFinish() fires. Sorry for that part so please disregard it since I'm still working on it I forgot to remove that part. My bad.

Comment: by the way @Houcine sorry I'm just a beginner on android development. I'm not familiar with the runOnUIThread() but now you've discussed it I think I will give it a shot on reading that one. Thank you for that.

Comment: @KaHel : i will post an example of it now, try it and let me know if it works

Comment: Sure, thanks for that man I'll try it out later. I'll give you a feedback as soon as I work on it.

Comment: @Houcine I think it has something to do with the fact that the timer isn't called exactly every second. Not sure it's the right direction, but I'd try to save the times of each tick in `onTick()` and see if the times add up nicely.

Comment: @MeLight : ok try it and let us know about that , i've posted and example of the class that extend the CountDownTimer ; i'm at work now and i can't do more than that to help :) .

Comment: @Houcine am at work too :) So can't be of much help now

Comment: @MeLight : lol , it's Okey  :)

Comment: I was having a similar problem where it would always stop at 1, then wait an extra second, then finish. My solution was to not put anything in the onFinish method and check when the global variable is zero to perform anything that would be in onFinish().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** **: this is your class that extended the** `CountDownTimer` :

```
public class GameTimer extends CountDownTimer{

private YourActivity context;
private int timer = 120;
private int endtime;
private TextView timer1,endTime1;

public gameTimer(YourActivity context, long startTime, long interval)
{
    // passing the context of your activity
    this.context = context;

    //get the textView to display results
    timer1 = (TextView)this.context.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    endTime1 = (TextView)this.context.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    super(startTime, interval);
}

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
   //on tick deduct timer by 1
  timer -= 1;  

  //override the method runOnUIThread 
  context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

      @override
      public void run(){
         timer1.setText(""+timer);
      }
  });        

}

public void onFinish()
{
    //PERFORM END ACTION UPON FINISHING THE GAME
    endtime = 120 - timer;

     //override the method runOnUIThread 
  context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

      @override
      public void run(){
         endTime1.setText(""+endtime);
      }
  });

}
}
```

**Second : in your activity ( on the method** `onCreate()` **, instanciate  your** `GameTimer` **and start it :**

```
//instanciate the GameTimer and pass the context to it
GameTimer gameTimer = new GameTimer(this, 120000, 1000);
    gameTimer.start();
```

Comment: Hi Houcine, sorry it's takes a while for me to reply on this one, well I've also tested this one but the result is just the same for my emulator. Well, I think I haven't mentioned it before that this problem only occurs in my emulator and by that time I haven't tested yet on an actual android phone. I've made a test on this one and found out that the millisUntilFinished doesn't give the expected value (millisUntilFinished - interval = expectedValue) which I think the main cause of the problem and therefore I conclude that this is just an emulator problem.

Comment: Well now I've tested this on my phone and the timer works fine. I've read about the one that you give and found out this will optimize my work so another thanks for this one. m(_ _)m

Comment: Thanks for `start()` method.