# Change color after specific time

Tags: android

How is it possible to make an app that changes between color automatically after specific time. My code doesn't work for some reason

```
    Random r = new Random();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    long m = System.nanoTime();
    int seconds = (int) (m/1000);

    if(seconds <= 5){
       ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
       ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

For ex. the screen is black and after specific time white. And that the time decreases itslef, the changing goes faster.

Comment: what color it is showing?

Comment: you need to put your `if condition` in `onTick()` method of timer, better use `CountdownTimer` see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483909/android-timer-ontick-problem

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following code for the color change.
Use the countdown timer for changing the color with condition.

```
new CountDownTimer(5000,1000)
{
     onFinish()
     {

          if(flag==1)
          {
                     //color set black
                     flag=0;
                     //start the countdown timer again.
           }
          else
           {
                     //color set white
                     flag=1;
                     //start the countdown timer again.
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert nanoseconds to seconds, but actually you are doing is not the same!!

try

```
int seconds = (int) (m/1000000000);
```

to convert to nan0-seconds to seconds

EDIT:

if you just want to keep changing color use this code:

```
public static int color = 1;
android.os.Handler customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

and its definition:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
{
        public void run()
        {
            //write here whaterver you want to repeat
            if(color == 1){
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            color = 2;
            }else{
              ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
              color = 1;
            }

            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);// will repeat after 5 seconds
        }
};
```

Comment: edited.. please try it.. you may not need any loop iteration anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Try following the code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
//Adding Log Statement to check

Log.i(Tag, String.valueOf(seconds);
if(seconds % 10 < 5){
       ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
       ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: Now the screen is only black.

Comment: Try Log to see Seconds values to understand better

Answer (score 1):

You can use tread to manage this, try this . thread will be the best way to achieve this, since you want to continuously change the color at regular interval.

```
Handler handler ;
LinearLayout ll ;
int i = 0;
int colors[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY};
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ll.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
        i++;
     }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ......
    .......
    handler  = new Handler();
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    Thread myTread = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true){
                    sleep(3000);
                    handler.post(runnable);

                }

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

    };
    myTread.start();
}
```

the code will change the background color every 3secs`sleep(3000)` as written in the code. also each time it changes it select from a set of pre-define color array.

you can also use random generation of colors. either you randomly generate the `rgb` values or you can store the colors in an array as i have done and randomly iterate over it